# Django Save Image Path to Database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, model

I'm new to Django and I want to save the image path to the Postgres database. I'm asked to use Charfield in my model not Imagefield. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you use a `CharField`? An `ImageField` is behind the curtains a `CharField`, but with extra logic to make retrieving the file, etc. more convenient. It also has some logic in place on where to store the image.

Comment: My team leader wants to use charfield. I usually use Imagefield.

Comment: well this looks like a (severe) [*primitive obsession* anti-pattern](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

Comment: tell me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CharField` to upload an image is not possible and it doesn't make any sense to use it.

You can use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) instead. It's a model type field specific for that.

If your team leader is asking you to use `CharField`, you can kindly explain to him that it doesn't make any sense to use it while you have `ImageField` that's stable and secure enough to upload images.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will do that.